# VB6 How to edit a record in listview

Tags: listview, vb6

OK so im really desperate or i wouldn't have brought this up. please help.
my project (stock control) uses a listview to keep show the records in a Microsoft access database. Most of the controls i have figured out to help me: create new records, delete records and so on.
However i cant EDIT/UPDATE already existing records.
When i try to EDIT/UPDATE an existing record, a new record is created and completely replaces the first record in the table, so i would end up with 2 almost similar records and the first record in the table replaced.

```
    Private Sub editrec()
    'This is the code that SHOULD update and overwrite the exsiting record but it doesnt work
    rsStocks!Itname = txts_2.Text
    rsStocks!ItPrice = txts_3.Text
    rsStocks!InStock = txts_4.Text
    rsStocks!OrderLvl = txts_5.Text
    rsStocks!Supplier = txts_6.Text
    rsStocks!ID = dlg_stk.Text
    rsStocks!Dull = "q"

    rsStocks.Update
    end sub
```

And this is how the editrec private sub gets called upon.

```
Private Sub dlg_ok_Click()


If (txts_2.Text = "") Or (txts_3.Text = "") Or (txts_4.Text = "") Or (txts_5.Text = "") Or (txts_6.Text = "") Then
 aflag = True
 MsgBox ("please fill the appropriate fields!"), vbCritical
 End If


If (aflag = True) Or (bflag = True) Then
  'nothing is supposed to happen here mate
aflag = False
bflag = False
cflag = False
MsgBox ("Error occured"), vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub

Else
'editrec gets called here 
editrec
aflag = False
bflag = False
cflag = False

txts_2.Text = ""
txts_3.Text = ""
txts_4.Text = ""
txts_5.Text = ""
txts_6.Text = ""

MsgBox ("Please hit UPDATE to refresh list and unblock list"), vbCritical, "REFRESH"
End If
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

the Connection:

```
Public conn_mod As ADODB.Connection
Public rsUsers As ADODB.Recordset
Public rsSupp As ADODB.Recordset
Public rsStocks As ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub Connect()
    Set conn_mod = New ADODB.Connection
    pathx = App.Path & "\Databases\main.mdb"
    conn_mod.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & pathx
conn_mod.Open
End Sub

    Public Sub openUsers()
        Set rsUsers = New ADODB.Recordset
         rsUsers.Open "select * from Users", conn_mod, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    End Sub

     Public Sub openSupp()
          Set rsSupp = New ADODB.Recordset
        rsSupp.Open "select * from Supp", conn_mod, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    End Sub

    Public Sub openStocks()
        Set rsStocks = New ADODB.Recordset
        rsStocks.Open "select * from Stocks", conn_mod, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    End Sub
```

Futher info to help you:
.the adodb connections work just fine

PLEASE HELP, iv been stuck trying to figure how to work this for more than 5 days :/ i just want to EDIT/UPDATE and overwrite the existing record.

Comment: Where do you select the record the user is editing? When you start updating the field values are you sure your recordset is positioned on the record you want to update?

Comment: The listview is in the "main" form. when a record in the listview is double clicked it open a "sub" form to edit and save. I think thats the problem, the record is not being selected, just the values are being called to the "sub" form and then saved as a new record and not being used to overwrite. So how do you specifically select a record for editing using listview? thanks for the reply @jac

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly that you are using a read-only cursor. I can't tell for sure, because you don't include the code that creates and opens your rsStocks variable. You'll want to investigate the CursorType property if you're unfamiliar with it.  The default cursor type is forward only, which isn't writeable.  Writeable cursor types are keyset and dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for replying this quickly man. there i added the connection as well and changed it from static to dynamic, but still the same thing. i wont overwrite, just creates a new record with the edited values and replaces the first record in the table.

Answer (score 0):

@jac @BobRodes 
thanks for answering the question. i got it working, finally.
jac you were right, the record wasnt being selected properly to be edited.
BobRodes thanks for telling me about the dynamic part, it helped.